# socket emitindo além da sala

Tags: socket.io

Todos os clients estão recebendo a mensagem pelo socket.io.
    Gostaria que somente os usuários que estiverem na sala recebessem.

***Server.js***

```
sockets.on('connection', function (action) {
   action.join('testroom');

   action.on('say to someone', function(msg){
      sockets.to('testroom').emit('some event', msg);
   });

});
```

Cliente no qual emite a mensagem:

***Client A***

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
   socket.emit('join', 'testroom');
});

socket.on('some event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

$('form').submit(function () {
   event.preventDefault();
   socket.emit('say to someone', $('#m').val() );
   $('#m').val('');
});
```

Cliente que está recebendo a mensagem indevidamente:

***Client B***

```
socket.on('connect',(socket) => {
    socket.on('some event', data => {
      console.log(data);
    });

});
```

Ps:  O client B está sendo utilizado em VueJs.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo estou na rua agora mas acredito que o seu problema seja

```js
sockets.on('connection', function (action) {
   action.join('testroom');

   action.on('say to someone', function(msg){

    //essa parte aqui 
      sockets.to('testroom').emit('some event', msg);


      //Mude para isso// onde o 'io' é a variavel onde voce armazenou o socket.io // Exemplo : var io = require('socket.io')(http);
      
      io.sockets.in('testroom').emit('some event', msg);
      
   });

});
```